# ressource a routing file in xml

Tags: xml, symfony, routes

In routing.yml I can ressource other routing configs with:

```
leaphly_cart:
type: rest
resource: '@AppXXXBundle/Resources/config/rest.xml'
prefix:   /api/v1/
```

And rest.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

  <routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

      <import id="carts" type="rest" resource="leaphly_cart.cart.limited.controller" name-prefix="api_1_" />
      <import id="cartItems" type="rest" resource="leaphly_cart.cart_item.limited.controller" name-prefix="api_1_" parent="carts" />
      <import id="carts_full" type="rest" resource="leaphly_cart.cart.full.controller" name-prefix="api_1_full_" prefix="/full" />
      <import id="cartItems_full" type="rest" resource="leaphly_cart.cart_item.full.controller" name-prefix="api_1_full_" parent="carts_full" prefix="/full" />
      <import id="cartTransitions" type="rest" resource="Leaphly\CartBundle\Controller\CartTransitionsController" name-prefix="api_1_" parent="carts" />

  </routes>
```

But this doesn't work...and show error :

```
InvalidArgumentException: [ERROR 1845] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/routing}routes': No matching global declaration available for the validation root. (in /var/www/app.com/web/ - line 5, column 0)
```

What's wrong in this ?

Comment: Are you missing the `</routes>` or is it just copy/paste mistake?

Comment: I miss to mention </route> at the end. I have updated the code in the same.

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your question to reflect the one in your actual code. The lines in your `routing.yml` wouldn't work in their current form either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **XML validation** fails because there are attributes present that symfony's standard routing xsd does not include/allow ( i.e. the `name-prefix` attribute).

Add `FOSRestBundle/Resources/config/schema/routing/`**[`rest_routing-1.0.xsd`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/schema/routing/rest_routing-1.0.xsd)** to your xml file and the validation won't fail.